# Knockout js form submit to spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

How to pass form parameters into spring controller.
I need to submit the below form into this url "submit.htm".

```
<form data-bind="submit: save" action="forms/submit.htm" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User: <span data-bind='text: errors().length'></span> errors</legend>
        <label>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName'/></label>
        <label>Last name: <input data-bind='value: lastName'/></label>
    </fieldset>
    <button  type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = {
    firstName: ko.observable().extend({
        required: true,
        minLength: 2,
        maxLength: 10
    }),
    lastName: ko.observable().extend({
        required: true
    }),
    tasks: ko.observableArray([]),
    save: function() {
        if (viewModel.errors().length == 0) {
            ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], this);
        } else {
            alert('Please check your submission.');
            viewModel.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
    }
};

viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(viewModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

this is going to my controller.
But I didnot get those parameters in my controller. Also I dont know the way to get these params in my controller.

Comment: Does the `ko.utils.postJson()` send the form data as JSON in the request body or as request parameters?

Comment: Thanks for your response nickdos. That is what I dont know

Comment: You should be able to use Firebug or Chrome developer tools to inspect the Ajax request in the browser to see which it is sending - even without a functioning end point.

Comment: Yes Nickdos, my data is passing to controller. But I don't know how to receive in my spring controller. We need to submit form as ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], {userList : {firstName:this.firstName(),lastName:this.lastName()}});

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/25397899/2182503